# How to test if exception in ok in unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, assert

I have a question about unittest. 
How to make a test to see if is there an exception?
an example:

Datum(3,32,2012)

If i call class Datum like this, where month is not in range (>31), it's everything OK, it throws an Exception and thats OK. But I want to make an unittest if Exception is OK, if is catching an exception ok..?
I made some test but and these were only with True values, and they are ok. I have no idea how to test in this way.. and search on internet..
thanks for reply.

```
import date,datetime

class Datum():
    def __init__(self,day,month,year):
        try:
            d=int(day)
            dvm=stevilodnivmesecu(month,year)
            if (d>=1 and d<=dvm):
                self.d=d
            else:
                raise Exception("Day out of moth range")
        except:
            raise ValueError("Day is not a number")
        try:
            m=int(month)
            if m>=1 and m<=12:
                self.m=m
            else:
                raise Exception("Month out of range")
        except:
            raise ValueError("Month is not a number")
        try:
            l=int(year)
            if l>=1000 and l<=9999:
                self.l=l
            else:
                raise Exception("Year is out of range")
        except:
            raise ValueError("Year is not a number")

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.d)+"."+repr(self.m)+"."+repr(self.l)

def monthrange(month,year):
    if month==2:
        if jeprestopno(year)==True:
            return 29
        elif jeprestopno(year)==False:
            return 28
    elif month>=1 and month<=7:
        if month%2!=0:
            return 31
    elif month>7 and month<=12:
        if month%2==0:
            return 31
    elif month>=1 and month<=7:
        if month%2==0:
            return 30
    elif month>7 and month<=12:
        if month%2!=0:
            return 30
    else:
        pass

def oneplusyear(year):
    if year%4==0 or (year!=100 and year%4==0) or (year%400==0 and year%100==0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Your exception handling here is very broad.  Bare "except" is very dangerous, and you're using it around4 statements at a time, just to see if a string couldn't be converted to an int.

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError,Datum,3,32,2012)
```

in your `unittest.TestCase` test to assert that `Datum(3,32,2012)` raises a `ValueError`.

Reference:

- [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual) on the various types of `asserts` you can make in
  TestCases.